# Import column with multiple values in data.frame r

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I would like to create a data.frame in R with some columns with more than one value. The dataframe is originated by importing a csv containing several columns with multiple values. Here is an example of the dataframe:

```
name fruit

john    banana, orange, apple
isaac    apple
```

I want to know if there is any way to separate the data in csv so when they are imported they will not be treated as a single string. And also after being differentiated and applied a factor (), if they would stay in that format:

```
> levels(fruit)
 [1] "banana"                                                                                        
 [2] "orange"                                     
 [3] "apple"
```

Comment: What you want to do is to store a list in a data.frame cell

Comment: exactly, but I would like to know if there is any way to change something in csv or there is some function to import the data as a list and not as a single string, because there is a lot of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is store a list in a data.frame cell. To build your list use `strsplit`

```
df$fruits = sapply(df$fruit, function(s)strsplit(s, ", "))
```

Regarding your levels, I think you are asking a bit too much